# What are some ways to covertly administer poisons?

Tags: poisons

Looking to poison the protagonist of a story, who is inside a home currently (not their own). Poisoner is a third party outside the home, and I was considering having them come to the front door as a salesperson or delivery man. I'd also appreciate suggestions not specific to these circumstances, just for future reference.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question, however one of my favorite murder tools is the Assassin's Teapot. The video may explain why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkrgUT70Mbo

Comment: Does collateral damage matter, or are you only wanting to poison the protagonist.

Comment: If you do not care about what poison, some crazy method of delivering it and so on or how a method of assassination would've developed given certain social structures - and similar things - this is more of a question for a writers board I fear. If this is not true, please specify. Anyways, for an efficient method you need to specify how that poison works. Instant death or slowly over a couple of months? How does it enter the body?

Comment: @JoshKing I'd like it to be limited to the protagonist

Comment: @Raditz_35 The poison should act in the space of a few minutes, and there's no real requirement for how it enters, aside from needing to be unnoticeable to the protagonist.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Coraline. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing answers to problems you are having in your world, rather than your story or plot. Additionally, "What are some ways to do X?" questions are inherently broad, especially when lacking constraints on which answers can be judged as "best." If you could [edit] your post to indicate how it is about worldbuilding, instead of story building, and add objective answer criteria, the community would appreciate it. Otherwise, this is liable to be put on hold until such clarification is provided.

Comment: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UE9UlccM0eQ/VraqRi8V0YI/AAAAAAAABCA/xZ3P3Oyybok/s1600/Captura%2Bde%2Bpantalla%2B2016-02-07%2Ba%2Blas%2B3.21.10.png

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest the way romans emperors used to have: rings that contain a secret container that holds the poison (normaly in a dust-like form). It's very discrete and quick to apply.

To fit the situation you mentioned, I suggest that the person who will poison the protagonist should be handing samples of this new "juice" door to door. He would simply put the poison in one plastic cup filled with juice and hand it to the protagonist (to look less suspicious he could also have more plastic cups).
[image: ring with opened lid]

The only problem is that I don't know what poison it was (the name), but I'm sure a short research and you'll find the name (if you don't already have a poison).

Comment: Cool. The practice of "clinking" wine glasses comes from a practice where you would pour wine into each other's cups, ensuring that no-one would risk poisoning the wine, lest the get poisoned themselves. Shaking hands is meant to dislodge hidden weapons from sleeves

Comment: @RenegadePizzaGuy thats interesting! :-)

Comment: Probably arsenic. It was considered "the king of poisons" by the Borgia, and that's quite a recommendation. It's not because it was extremely lethal - though it is quite toxic - but because it was odorless, tasteless and transparent. It could be administered in most of foods without being detected by taste or smell.

Comment: @Rekesoft cool o.o

Answer (score 0):

## Food

Posing as a food delivery man, the assassin poisons the food. Fairly straightforward.

## Water

The assassin does some mischievous plumbing work and poisons the family. Perhaps installs a pipe that is coated in some poison?

## Air

The air conditioning is broken? Okay, the assassin fixes it and also rigs it to pump out nerve gas.

## Medicine

Swap some advil with some poisons and tehy won't know what hit them.

Comment: The only modality missing that I can think of is touch. Bumping into someone is one approach. Coating something that they will handle is another.